# How do I know if an algorithm is stable?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was given a bunch of sorting algorithms to analyze and determine if they are stable or not.
I know that that an algorithm is stable if two objects with equal keys appear in the same order in sorted output as they appear in the input unsorted array.
But I don't know how to determine that when it comes to code. what criteria should I use?

Thanks

Comment: Use the Feynman method, see esp. step two (but do be sure not to skip step one as you have here!): 1. Write down the problem. 2. Think really hard. 3. Write down the solution.

Comment: 1. Find the code that reorders.  2. Prove that it always leaves equal keys in the same order by using assertions.

Comment: If using adjacent swaps only (like bubble sort), and if equal keys are considered to be in order, then it should be stable. If using non-adjacent swaps (like quick sort), it's unstable, for example swapping (array[i], array[j]), with array[i+1] == array[j] (before the swap) since the order of equal elements is reversed. If using merge and if equal keys are merged in order, the sort is stable. I'm not sure what would be considered as proof of stability.

Comment: if for each item except the last in the resulting array A[i] <= A[i + 1] is true ( if ascending order )

Comment: By examining the code, you should be able to determine if a swap could move an item multiple spaces to the left or right, potentially moving past an item that has equal value. If that's possible, then the sort is not stable.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem and was wondering if there was a better way to do it. Only way to improve it was to use a better algorithm for searching duplicates. At this time, I am only iterating through array for every element in array which is slow. Anyways, to answer your question what you should do is create an int array if your array to be sorted is not massive. Initialize it with a[i] = i. As you sort the original array, sort this one too. This will give you where your initial positions of the original array went. Then search for duplicates in the original array, if you find any and new position of the left duplicate is greater than new position of the right duplicate, array is not stable. There might be better methods out there but this is the first solution I came up with. Cheers and good luck with your classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go all the way to implementing and less algorithm analysis, you can store your integer array as a struct that have the keys `value`and `order`.

- First iterate your array, and determine the `order`. Every time you see the same number, you increment order by one.
- Modify your sorting algorithm to read `element.value`. It should be quite simple to modify that way.
- Sort your array.
- Check the orders in your sorted array. The orders should also be sorted for each value if the algorithm is stable.

This is probably not the way your they ask you to do and is no way optimized but if you want to demonstrate, *this works.*

---

This answer is a variation of @Darka Bakula's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simulate (mentally) the working of the algorithms when there are runs of equal elements and figure out if the algorithm will scramble them. Also, look at the comparisons and see what happens if you replace a strict equality by a non-strict one and conversely.